# External graphic GeoServer SLD

Tags: geoserver

I want to add an external graphic but it doesn't work and here is the code I put the PNG photo in the workspace style folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>a1</sld:Name>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>group0</sld:Name>
                <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>generic:geometry</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>simple</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>New Rule</sld:Name>
                    
                       <sld:PointSymbolizer> 
           <sld:Graphic> 
             <sld:ExternalGraphic>
               <sld:OnlineResource  xlink:type= "simple"  xlink:href= "1.png"  /> 
               <sld:Format> image/png </sld:Format> 
             </sld:ExternalGraphic> 
           < /sld:Graphic>  
         </sld:PointSymbolizer>
                    
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>longitude</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12.0</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>1.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>0.0</sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Displacement>
                                    <sld:DisplacementX>-25.0</sld:DisplacementX>
                                    <sld:DisplacementY>-9.0</sld:DisplacementY>
                                </sld:Displacement>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>default rule</sld:Name>
                    <sld:PointSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Graphic>
                            <sld:Mark>
                                <sld:Fill>
                                    <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#1B9E77</sld:CssParameter>
                                </sld:Fill>
                                <sld:Stroke/>
                            </sld:Mark>
                            <sld:Size>47</sld:Size>
                        </sld:Graphic>
                    </sld:PointSymbolizer>
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>latitude</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12.0</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>0.0</sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                                <sld:Displacement>
                                    <sld:DisplacementX>23.0</sld:DisplacementX>
                                    <sld:DisplacementY>-7.0</sld:DisplacementY>
                                </sld:Displacement>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: how are you using the style? Does it work if you make it a proper URL with `file://` etc at the start? what does the relevant part of the log say happened?

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Look up what a file URL looks like, or use the style editor in geoserver to do it for you. Also you need to add the relevant part of the log file